# Python Extract Not matching indexes in two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames master and slave. Both will have the same indexes, sometimes, the master will have more. I want to extract those additional indexes and corresponding data.
**My code:**

```
masterdf = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.arange(1.0,9.0)},index=pd.date_range(start='2020-05-04 08:00:00', freq='1h', periods=8))
sldf= pd.DataFrame({'A':np.arange(1.0,5.0)},index=pd.date_range(start='2020-05-04 08:00:00', freq='1h', periods=6))

auxdf = masterdf.reindex(masterdf.index-sldf.index)
```

**Present output:**

```
ValueError: cannot add indices of unequal length
```

Comment: do you mean you want to create a dataframe containing only the rows of masterdf that are not found in sldf?

Comment: Your code for creating sldf does not work.  I modified the `arange` parameter to `np.arange(1.0,7.0)` instead to make it work.

Comment: @TallChuck That's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the [`Index.difference()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) to get the difference of the 2 indexes for the `.reindex()`:

```
auxdf = masterdf.reindex(masterdf.index.difference(sldf.index))
```

Result:

```
masterdf = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.arange(1.0,9.0)},index=pd.date_range(start='2020-05-04 08:00:00', freq='1h', periods=8))
sldf= pd.DataFrame({'A':np.arange(1.0,7.0)},index=pd.date_range(start='2020-05-04 08:00:00', freq='1h', periods=6))

auxdf = masterdf.reindex(masterdf.index.difference(sldf.index))



print(auxdf)


                       A
2020-05-04 14:00:00  7.0
2020-05-04 15:00:00  8.0
```